# How to save Element from Jsoup to database

Tags: java, database, jsoup

I use Jsoup get all data from website  and save element if match some content when i get. I want when we get element. If it match some thing character , I save element from database(MYSQL,Postgress...). I code look like :

```
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("https://viblo.asia");
                Document doc = conn.userAgent("Mozilla").get();
                Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("post-feed").get(0).children();
                Elements list = new Elements();
                Elements strings = new Elements();
                for (Element element : elements) {
                    if (element.hasClass("post-feed-item")) {
                        list.add(element);
                        Element e = element.children().get(1).children().get(1).children().get(0);
                        if (e.text().matches("^.*?(Docker|docker|DOCKER).*$")) {
                            strings.add(e);
                            //save to element to DB
                        }

                    }
                }

                for (Element page : elements) {
                    if (links.add(URL)) {
                        //Remove the comment from the line below if you want to see it running on your editor
                        System.out.println(URL);
                    }
                    getPageLinks(page.attr("abs:href"));
                }
```

I want if title from element contain : "Docker" it save my element to Database. But in element, It contain div and some thing link url, img , content. How to i save it to database. What if I want to save each element in a field in a database that is feasible? If not I can convert element to html and save it? Please help.

Example html i want save data base:

```
<div class="post-feed-item">
 <a href="/u/HoanKi"><img src="https://images.viblo.asia/avatar/1d0e5458-ad41-4d1c-89db-292dc198b4fa.png" srcset="https://images.viblo.asia/avatar/1d0e5458-ad41-4d1c-89db-292dc198b4fa.png 1x, https://images.viblo.asia/avatar-retina/1d0e5458-ad41-4d1c-89db-292dc198b4fa.png 2x" class="avatar avatar--md mr-05"></a>
 <div class="post-feed-item__info">
  <div class="post-meta--inline">
   <div class="user--inline d-inline-flex">
    <!---->
    <a href="/u/HoanKi" class="mr-05">Hoàn Kì</a>
    <!---->
   </div>
   <div class="post-meta d-inline-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
    <div class="text-muted mr-05">
     <span class="mr-05">about 3 hours ago</span>
     <button title="Copy URL" class="icon-btn _13z_mK0hRyRB3dPzawysKe_0"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-link"></i></button>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <!---->
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-title--inline">
   <h3 class="word-break mr-05"><a href="/p/docker-chua-biet-gi-den-biet-dung-phan-3-docker-compose-3P0lPm6p5ox" class="link">Docker: Chưa biết gì đến biết dùng (Phần 3 docker-compose )</a></h3>
   <div class="tags" data-v-cbe11868>
    <a href="/tags/docker" class="el-tag _3wKNDsArij9ZFjXe8k4ryR_0 el-tag--info el-tag--mini" data-v-cbe11868>Docker</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!---->
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
   <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="stats">
     <span title="Views" class="stats-item text-muted"><i aria-hidden="true" class="stats-item__icon fa fa-eye"></i> 62 </span>
     <span title="Clips" class="stats-item text-muted"><i aria-hidden="true" class="stats-item__icon fa fa-paperclip"></i> 1 </span>
     <span title="Comments" class="stats-item text-muted"><i aria-hidden="true" class="stats-item__icon fa fa-comments"></i> 0 </span>
    </div>
    <!---->
   </div>
   <div title="Score" class="points">
    <div class="carets">
     <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
     <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
    <span class="text-muted">4</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the post **title** that contains **docker** key word, am I correct?

Comment: can you show me some sample content from to `url` / website you are searching? I guess you want this content - **Tự tạo Helpers trong dự án Laravel** from the page.

Comment: I had edit post. If i search match keyword : "Docker" from String "Docker: Chưa biết gì đến biết dùng (Phần 3 docker-compose )" from title i want save all element in div as above

Comment: currently what portion of that html get saved in the database? post that too.

Comment: I want save all element with class "<div class="post-feed-item">" into database

Comment: okay. I understand. do you know how to save data in **mysql** database using `jdbc`?

Comment: Yes. Mysql,Postgres or H2

Comment: okay then, all you need it to modify your logic a little bit and add a **BLOB** data type column at your table to which you want to store.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. Could you tell me how to i get url link page from https://viblo.asia/ ? . Code as above only get page 1. It can't get 823 page. Because it using bootstrap paging. When i get it, it only get 12 page. But it contain 823 page. How to i get all.

Comment: do you know the total page count beforehand or you need to get total page count from the web page? in either case you can traverse all page and get your post feeds.

Comment: how to i traverse all page. Because it use bootstrap. It only show 12 page when i loop on it.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, modify your logic for fetching `post-feed-item` like this-

```
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("https://viblo.asia");
Document doc = conn.userAgent("Mozilla").get();

Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("post-feed-item"); //This will get the whole element.

for (Element element : elements) {
    String postFeeds = "";

    if (element.toString().contains("docker")) {
        postFeeds = postFeeds.concat(element.toString());  
        //save postFeeds to DB
    }
}
```

#### Extra

```
/**
 * Your parsed element may contain single quote ('). 
 * This will cause error while persisting.
 * to avoid this you need to escape single quote (')
 * with double single quote ('')
 */

 if (element.toString().contains("docker")) {
     postFeeds = postFeeds.concat(element.toString().replaceAll("'", "''"));  
     //save postFeeds to DB
 }
```

Second, *What if I want to save each element in a field in a database that is feasible?*

You don't need separate columns to store each element at the database. However you can save but the feasibility depends on your use case. If you just want to store the `post-feed-items` only for writing it back to your web page then it is not feasible.

Third, *How can I convert element to html and save?*

You don't need to convert the `element` to `html` but you need to convert the `element` to `String` if you want to save it the database.
All you need is a column type of **BLOB** data type (you can also save it as *VARCHAR* but *BLOB* is safer).

#### Update

*How can I traverse all pages?*

By looking at the source code of that page I found this is how you can get the total page number -

```
Elements pagination = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching("href", "page=\\d");

int totalPageNo = Integer.parseInt(pagination.get(pagination.size() - 2).text());
```

then loop through each page.

```
for(int page = 1; page <= totalPageNo; page++) {
    Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("https://viblo.asia/?page=" + page);
    //rest of your code
}
```

Comment: "You don't need to convert the element to html but you need to convert the element to String if you want to save it the database."  If i want get specific element from it and save to database. Example: I want to get image , URL I must loop element and get it. After that, I save it to database. Right ?

Comment: that's right. First loop through and get your desired element, convert it to string and finally persist it to the database.

Comment: So can i use multiple threads from it ? I mean website i get have lot page , I want used multiple threads get post same time ? It possible ?

Comment: you can use multiple threads but you need to split the page numbers accordingly so that you don't end up getting same post multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I properly know what's your mean.Here are some views:
*First you should clearify what`s your search for and make fields of tables in database. Such as according your ideas, you can make a table_docker table in db and there are field_id,field_content,field_start_time,field_links and so on in it.* 
 *Second you should code some utils of classes such as JsoupUtils which is get HTML and parse it , HtmlUtils which is used to handle the html remarks and download these pictures,DBUtils which is used to connect db and save data,POIUtils which is used to show your data,DataUtils which is used to handle your data by your ways.*

Comment: Thank. But how to i save div from html to database

Comment: some html remarks can not save to db,so if you want save div or something else you need escape this html text which contains html remarks,then just save to db.Use the Apache commons-lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml() to escape html.

Comment: I had parse element to string using method element.outerHTML. It now string. I can save it to db ? Or I must spit it to string and save to db ?